# Targeting R+ (version 30 and above) requires the resources.arsc of installed APKs to be stored uncompressed and aligned on a 4-byte boundary

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to update android target API from 29 to 30. I have updated:

```
compileSdkVersion           = 30
targetSdkVersion            = 30
buildToolsVersion           = "30.0.2"
```

The app is aligned with  `zipalign -p -f -v 4` before signing as per the official documentation.

When I try to `adb install` the `.apk` however I get:

> Failure [-124: Failed parse during installPackageLI: Targeting R+
> (version 30 and above) requires the resources.arsc of installed APKs
> to be stored uncompressed and aligned on a 4-byte boundary]

Has anyone had any success with that?

Answer (score 12):

I had a similar issue.

Observe the zipalign logs for this - [image]

It should not be compressed. If it is, then that is the issue. Somehow you need to make it not compressed. It should look like

```
resources.arsc (OK)
```

Give this a try -

```
unzip -q -o ur-apk.apk -d ur-unzipped-apk-folder
cd ./ur-unziped-apk-folder
zip -n "resources.arsc" -qr ../zipped.apk *
```

Use this zipped.apk for alignment and signing as per the official doc.

Note - Apps that target Android 11 (API level 30) or higher can't be installed if they contain a compressed resources.arsc file or if this file is not aligned on a 4-byte boundary

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/behavior-changes-11#app-packaging
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline#sign_cmdline

Comment: I did this but apk has missing drawables which results in a crash. Before this, I had 227, after doing this, it's 202.

Comment: After doing this,When I run `zipalign -c -v $apk` I got error as follows: 
`44624729 resources.arsc (BAD - 1)`

Comment: Based on your comment, I wrote [a set of scripts available on GitHub](https://github.com/mathieures/convert-apk/) to convert any `.apk` to a version compatible with Android 11 and above. It basically just uncompresses `resources.arsc` and recompresses the rest. There is also another script to align and sign the new `.apk` just for convenience. The `.bat` version for cmd.exe and the `.sh` one is for Linux or Git Bash on Windows.

Answer (score 7):

**If you zipalign and then sign with an old version of `jarsigner` then it will unalign during the signing!**

Be sure to use the newer `apksigner`.  On my system it is in `~/Android/Sdk/build-tools/32.0.0/apksigner`

Here is my repack-n-sign script.  Note that you may need to update your BUILD_TOOLS path and set it to the right location:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

BUILD_TOOLS=~/Android/Sdk/build-tools/32.0.0/

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
        echo "usage: $0 your-app.apk"
        exit 1
fi

DIR=`mktemp -d`
DN=`dirname "$1"`
BN=`basename "$1"`
OUT="$DN/repacked-$BN"
OUT_ALIGNED="$DN/aligned-$BN"
OUT_SIGNED="$DN/signed-$BN"

# Debug mode
set -x

# Repack without the META-INF in case it was already signed
# and flag resources.arsc as no-compress:
unzip -q "$1" -d "$DIR"
pushd .
cd $DIR

rm -rf "$DIR/META-INF"
zip -n "resources.arsc" -r ../repacked.$$.apk *

popd

mv "$DIR/../repacked.$$.apk" "$OUT"

# Align
rm -f "$OUT_ALIGNED"
"$BUILD_TOOLS"/zipalign -p -v 4 "$OUT" "$OUT_ALIGNED"

# Verify
"$BUILD_TOOLS"/zipalign -vc 4 "$OUT_ALIGNED"

# Sign
"$BUILD_TOOLS"/apksigner sign -verbose -ks ~/my-release-key.keystore --out "$OUT_SIGNED" "$OUT_ALIGNED"

# Cleanup
rm -rf "$DIR"

echo == Done: $OUT_ALIGNED
```

Comment: I did this but apk has missing drawables which results in a crash. Before this, I had 227, after doing this, it's 202.

Comment: Maybe the `rm -rf "$DIR/META-INF"` line is not right for your build?  I cleared out META-INF on mine because I was re-signing an existing package.  I've not done any android dev, just repacked an existing build, so not sure what to suggest.  Except for META-INF everything should be the same.

Comment: Somehow the --out parameter for apksigner didn't work, i just removed the parameters in order for it to sign over the same file.

Comment: Well it didn't work, haha, I end up now with Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION]

Comment: @htafoya, what does `apksigner --version` report?  For the 32.0.0 SDK, apksigner's version is 0.9: maybe yours is old?  Not sure why --out would be missing.

Comment: running logcat it was because editing assets files require me to update the manifest digest

Answer (score 1):

Note to anyone using [capacitor](https://capacitorjs.com/) if you're having this issue...

Simply change your `capacitor.config.js` file to use the `apksigner`. It uses the `jarsigner` by default.

The options is:

```js
{
  ...otherOptions,
  android: {
    buildOptions: {
      signingType: 'apksigner'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I would add, that you have to make sure that capacitor/android is at least version 5.1. On windows, you also need that the path to apksigner is in the environment variables (PATH-TO-ANDROID-SDK\build-tools\VERSION-NUMBER\)

Comment: @Mathieu Absolutely... That one even bit me... not adding the path var

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the zipalign issue.

Use the below command before signing the apk

Step 1:  `zipalign -p -f -v 4 generated.apk firstzipaligned.apk` (here verification will fail)

Step 2:  `zipalign -p -f -v 4 firstzipaligned.apk final.apk` (verification will pass)

Use `final.apk` to sign your application. Refer to [zipalign documentation](https://developer.android.com/tools/zipalign).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).