# Signing an 3rd partry apk with v2 signing scheme

Tags: android, android-studio, apktool, apksigner

Recently I have been trying to debug a 3rd party android application using a variery of tools.
I have followed the directions in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jdxFfG8gICw&lc=UgydMVaCB75YQSCr2kp4AaABAg.9gwJGOhxv7s9gwpIdtVmd7&ab_channel=RingZeroLabs). These were the main steps **presented in the attached video**:

1. deassemble the original apk - **apktool (2.6.1)**
2. Change/Add the `android:debugaable='true'` property in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file - **Manually**.
3. build an **unsigned apk** using the previous level directory - **apktool (2.6.1)**.
4. sign the apk - **dex2jar.d2j-apk-sign (2.2-SNAPSHOT)**
5. Install the app into an emulator on android studio (*emulator stats are described below) -
   using **adb** on android sdk.

However, I have faced trouble in signing and installing the apk in the emulator.
I have tried a variety of tools and options in order to fix the issue:

1. **Using `d2j-apk-sign`** - The signing itself seemed to have worked, but the installion didn't.

   I received the error:

   ```
   adb: failed to install C:\Users\user\Desktop\Moovit_Stuff\chess_signed.apk: Failure [-124: 
   Failed parse during installPackageLI: Targeting R+ (version 30 and above) requires the 
   resources.arsc of installed APKs to be stored uncompressed and aligned on a 4-byte boundary]
   ```
2. **Using zipalign and apksigner (sdk 33.0.0)** - I have used the information on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69667830/targeting-r-version-30-and-above-requires-the-resources-arsc-of-installed-apk). accrroding to KJ7LNW's comment there, zipalign should be used and then a different tool named `apksigner`. zipalign worked perfectly, but afterwards,
   apksigner requires a keystore file. I have created one in android studio (jks file), but after using it received the following error.

   ```
   Failed to load signer "signer #1"
   java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
           at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
           at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
           at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
           at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
           at java.security.KeyStore.load(Unknown Source)
           at com.android.apksigner.SignerParams.loadKeyStoreFromFile(SignerParams.java:362)
           at     
   com.android.apksigner.SignerParams.loadPrivateKeyAndCertsFromKeyStore(SignerParams.java:248)
           at com.android.apksigner.SignerParams.loadPrivateKeyAndCerts(SignerParams.java:181)
           at com.android.apksigner.ApkSignerTool.getSignerConfig(ApkSignerTool.java:419)
           at com.android.apksigner.ApkSignerTool.sign(ApkSignerTool.java:336)
           at com.android.apksigner.ApkSignerTool.main(ApkSignerTool.java:92)
   ```

   I have tried to change the extension to .keystore but it didn't work either.
3. (2.1)  **Using r0adkll's comment on** [this](https://github.com/r0adkll/sign-android-release/issues/1) - in order to fix the keystore file. (using `openssl base64`, didn't change the result)

if you have reached this point, I want to thank you and I would greatly appreciate it if you could try and assist me.

Thanks in advance!

**Notes:

1. apk file that I used - [here](https://easyupload.io/ogroxo)
2. emulator stats - Pixel & android tiramisu (version 33, x86_64)